# response.write within callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS and following this book(http://www.nodebeginner.org/).

This code is from that book and this function did not list the files inside the current directory which was supposed to happen.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response){
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    exec("ls -lah",function(error,stdout,stderr){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();
   });

}
```

Then I changed the code to print the return value of response.write function as follows. And when I run it printed "true" on command line. That is return value is "true".

```
function start(response){
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    exec("ls -lah",function(error,stdout,stderr){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
        console.log(response.write(stdout));
        response.end();
   });

}
```

Can anyone explain the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you on linux env?

Comment: I didn t think response.write return anything, you should try `console.log(stdout)`

Comment: @Akshay No I am not. I just noticed that... And when I print the error it says "ls" not recognized as a command. May be thats the problem. But when I put remove response.write(stdout) with response.write("test") still it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @DrakaSAN It does return. Check here http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for it. The code you have sent is too little to take a judgement on. Have you used response.end() somewhere else?

Comment: @TavionPotter: On which os are you? Maybe ls isn t supported and so don t output, which make response.write write... nothing. It would appear blank on the page and return successfully.

Comment: Can you do a curl and get raw output from your http server?

Comment: @Akshay I have response.end() nowhere else. And this is all I have inside this file.

Comment: so, do you have any files in the dir?, Also if you do, how many do you have?

Comment: @DrakaSAN I am on windows 7

Comment: @TavionPotter: So you need to `exec('dir'`, not ls.

Comment: exec dir and not ls. Also put a check for stderr. if(!stderr)response.wr...

Comment: @DrakaSAN Tried that. doesnt work. Now, even response.write("test") doesnt work inside call back function.

Comment: @TavionPotter: Try to console.log before response.write, take one step before another: first make sure you get the data, then send it.

Comment: @DrakaSAN yeah.. I can see data when trying console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply that you try to execute `ls -lah` on windows's powershell.

Powershell's command to list files is `dir`, so your code will look like:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response){
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    exec("dir",function(error,stdout,stderr){ //<== dir instead of ls
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();
   });

}
```

Edit at Tavion Potter demand:

Check if there is no other response.end() in the file, node.js being asynchronous, you could have ended the response somewhere else.

Comment: It does not work.. Now, if I put response.write("test") here it should work anyway right? But that doesn't work either inside callback function.

Comment: Weird... Is this the only code you have? Or is there any concurent response.end?

Comment: Oops...... inside this file yes.. but there was one more response.end where routing happens. when I removed that it worked. Thank you.

Comment: If you can add that part too(checking if a response.end gets exeuted before callback function) to your reply, I can mark it as the answer here. Could you please do it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you print out value that's returned by expression **response.write(stdout)**

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(response.write(stdout));
```

Of course you are only seeing true, as response.write is internally writing to a file descriptor that is connect to the socket. If you just call response.write, you should see you data.